# Is there any FileZilla Server alternative (GUI based) in Linux?

Tags: software-rec, ftp, filezilla, pure-ftpd

I'm wondering is there any alternative to FileZilla server in Linux?

- I'm looking for a server with GUI manager which offers nearly zero configuration so I can run and manage FileZilla server within 5 min while PureFTPd needs at least 2 hrs and managing users and groups really painful, especially from a flat file.
- I tried to use Pure-Admin (GTK manager for PureFTPd) and I found it really stupid by comparison to FileZilla GUI manager

Answer (score 4):

I'd give [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/goals.html) a look. ProFTPD is just the server daemon but there are several GUIs that you can use to manage it. Also check out the [ProFTPD wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD) page for additional information as well as a link to a [comparison of other FTP servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_server_software).

#### GAdmin-ProFTPD

[GAdmin-ProFTPD](http://freecode.com/projects/gadmin-proftpd) is a GTK+ front end for GNOME and KDE, as a part of the [GAdmintools collection](http://dalalven.dtdns.net/linux/gadmintools-webpage/).

#### screenshot

[image: ss of GAdmin-ProFTPD]

#### proFTPd Administrator

[ProFTPD Administrator](http://proftpd-adm.sourceforge.net/) is a web based GUI. Screenshot are available [here](http://proftpd-adm.sourceforge.net/page_screenshot.php). It's built on PHP and uses a MySQL database to track the monitoring data of the ProFTPD server over time.

#### screenshot

Here's a shot of a user details page.
      [image: ss of user details]